# Moving to a method results in `undefined method`

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to combine two similar methods into a single one, but I'm having some problems.

Currently:

```
def self.tree
  self.projects.sort_by(&:name).map do |assembly|
    [ assembly, assembly.assemblies.map(&:tree) ]
  end
end

def tree
  [ self, self.assemblies.map(&:tree), self.parts ]
end
```

I've tried changing it to

```
def self.tree
  self.build_tree( self.projects )
end

def tree
  self.build_tree( [self] )
end

def build_tree( set )
  set.sort_by(&:name).map do |assembly|
    [ assembly, assembly.assemblies.map(&:tree), assembly.parts ]
  end
end
```

but I just get `undefined method 'build_tree' for #<Class:0x000000036a5588>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you probably call tree as a class method. in this case, this method try to call a static build_tree (self is the own Class). to work you need do something like that:

```
def self.build_tree(set)
   code...
end
```

Comment: +0 Ruby doesn't have static methods.

Comment: Sorry, it is a Class method. my bad.